# How to check current time against future time using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have stored posts with dates on my database, and the format of such dates is:

**yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss**

This is the format that the database returns because it is using the MySQL current_timestamp to insert it. Also, I **add** 20 minutes more to the post **(current_timestamp + INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)** to make it a future time.

What I want to do is the following:

This is a part of my post:

```
<div class="caption">
    <h3>Image</h3>
    <p class="timeShow">2014-01-09 11:22:20</p>
    <button class="vote btn btn-info" data-id="42" data-time="2014-01-09 11:22:20">Add Time</button>
</div>
```

The time that is returned in every post, is a future time.

**How do I check if the future time that is returned from the database and inserted into the data-time attribute in every post is higher than the current time?**

What I want to achieve is delete every post in which the current time is higher than the returned time of every post using JavaScript or jQuery, that way they can just disappear without reloading the page. Don't worry about deleting them from the database.

Thank you, and I apologize if some of this is confusing. I worded it as best as I could.

Comment: Be aware that you may face problems because of difference between server time and client time - which is what the browser access.

Comment: The posts get deleted in the server once the server's time reaches the time that was inserted in the database. @DontVoteMeDown, is there a big difference between server and database time?

Also, I see what you mean. That's actually a huge problem.

Comment: Is there a way to access the server's time and pass it onto JavaScript so that it may be checked against the server's future time?

Comment: You can get the time from server, calc the diff against client time, store it and use that diff to compare with future times. Anyway, this should works `(new Date("2014-01-09 11:22:20")).getTime() < (new Date()).getTime()`